# flexdashboard html file becomes extremely large with icon

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, icons, flexdashboard

If i create an html file with flexdashboard and an icon, the file is about 4.5 mb.
If i only leave out the icon and everything else stays the same, the size of the html file decreases to 0.7 mb. how is that possible and could i include the icon so that the file doesn't get so big?

````
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
````

## with ICON {data-icon="fa-sun"}

### Row {data-height=600}

#### Chart A

#### Chart B

#### Chart C

````
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
````

## without ICON {}

### Row {data-height=600}

#### Chart A

#### Chart B

#### Chart C